# Will photons be entangled in polarisation even when i know their polarisation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, conventions, crystals, quantum-states

Imagine if i have a KDP crystal (the property of the KDP crystal is, the polarisation of singnal and idler photons that come out by parametric down conversion is orthogonal to pump photon, and both the signal and idler photons share same polarisation) and i shine a +45° polarised light on to the crystal, then i know that the out coming photons must have -45° polarisation, the -45° polarisation is considered to be in superposition of linear and horizontal polarisation, so both the signal and idler photons are in superposition of linear and horizontal polarisation as they are -45° polarised, but they are entangled, means if i measure the polarisation of signal photon in vertical axis, and if i get the signal photon to be vertically polarised, then the idler photon will also be in vertically polarised state as they both are entangled right ?

Comment: Greetings! Please don’t re-ask a closed question. See [this help center page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and links therein for guidance.